# How can I break my flow on my observable to call another observable with RXJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have the nex flow with observable :

```
verifyFacebookUser2(): Observable<User> {       
    let userFacebook = {"type": "facebook", "id_facebook": this.userId};
    return this._us.verifyRegisterFacebookObs(userFacebook )
      .flatMap(token => {
        if (!token) {
          return Observable.of([])
        }
        else {
          return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.set('token', token));
        }
      }, error => {
        error => console.log("FIRST ERROR" + JSON.stringify(error));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.status === 404) {
          throw new Error("404");
        } else {
          throw new Error("");
        }
        //return Observable.of([])
      })
      .flatMap(res => {
        return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token'));
      })
      .flatMap(tokenStorage => {
        let decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(JSON.stringify(tokenStorage));
        let idUser = parseInt(decodedToken.id);
        return this._ups.getUserProfileObs(idUser);
      })
  }
```

As you can see, my observable return User if all flow is ok, my service verifyRegisterFacebookObs return an user :

```
verifyRegisterFacebookObs(user): Observable<any> {
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/verify';
    return this.http2.post(url, user)
      .map(res => res['result'])
      /*.catch(error => {
         if (error.status === 404)
           return Observable.of("");
      })*/
  }
```

So, this flow function well when all is ok , but How can I execute another flow or observable if my service return 404 error.

If my service return 404 error, it does mean that user doesnt exist and i need to 
 register this user calling a new http request

TO use that I do the next :

```
this.verifyFacebookUser2()
              .subscribe((user: User) => {
                alert("OK");               
              }, error => {
                alert(error);               
    // Can I call another function that call observable to do another flow ? 
                    this.registerIdFacebook(this.userId);    
                  })
```

If all is ok print ok , if I get error I need to call registerIdFacebook, so I only call to registerIdFacebook when error is emited by this._us.verifyRegisterFacebookObs(userFacebook ) and its 404.

```
 registerIdFacebook(id) {    
   this._us.facebookRegisterObs({"id_facebook": id}).
    subscribe(resultado => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(resultado));
    }, error => {
      //TODO PRESENT TOAST
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    })
  }
```

Could someone help me to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my question, and this is the answer :

1 . First, my service have to return observable if error status is 404:

```
 verifyRegisterFacebookObs(user): Observable<any> {
    let url = URL_SERVICIOS + '/users/verify';
    return this.http2.post(url, user)
      .map(res => res['result'])
      .catch(error => {
         if (error.status === 404)
           return Observable.of("");
      })
  }
```

2. I've modified my function verifyFacebookUser

   verifyFacebookUser(): Observable {
           let userFacebook = {"type": "facebook", "id_facebook": this.userId};

   ```
       return this._us.verifyRegisterFacebookObs(userFacebook)
         .flatMap(token => {
           if (!token) {
             return this._us.facebookRegisterObs({"id_facebook": this.userId}).flatMap(user => {
               return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.set('token', user.token));
             })
           }
           else {
             return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.set('token', token));
           }
         }, error => {
           error => console.log("FIRST ERROR" + JSON.stringify(error));
         })
         .flatMap(res => {
           return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('token'));
         })
         .flatMap(tokenStorage => {
           let decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(JSON.stringify(tokenStorage));
           let idUser = parseInt(decodedToken.id);
           return this._ups.getUserProfileObs(idUser);
         })
     }
   ```

As you can see if token doesnt exist, I call to this._us.facebookRegisterObs, inmediatly  save token to continue the flow.

Finally, I call like this way :

```
 this.subscription=this.verifyFacebookUser()
          .subscribe((user: User) => {
            this.processDataObs(user);
            loading.dismissAll();
          }, error => {
            console.log("Error on flow ---" + error);
            loading.dismissAll();
            this.presentToast("Ups... ha ocurrido un error con facebook");
          })
```

Dont Forget unsubsribe :

```
 ionViewWillLeave() {
    if (this.subscription)
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) :

You need to return an `Observable`, so directly call your _us service :

```
this.verifyFacebookUser2() {
  .catchError(() => this._us.facebookRegisterObs({"id_facebook": id}))
  .subscribe((user: User) => {
    alert('OK');
}
```

Or Change your registerIdFacebook to return the service method :

```
registerIdFacebook(id) {    
  return this._us.facebookRegisterObs({"id_facebook": id})
    .pipe(tap(
       (resultado) => {
         alert(JSON.stringify(resultado));
       }, 
       (error) => {
         //TODO PRESENT TOAST
         alert(JSON.stringify(error));
       }));
}


this.verifyFacebookUser2() {
  .catchError(() => this.registerIdFacebook(this.userId))
  .subscribe((user: User) => {
    alert('OK');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Florian but I dont understand completly, because i dont want to lose my flow done on verifyFacebookUser2, Could you re-write using my code please?

Comment: @SDLUJO I changed the way you call your method. You won't lose anything. You don't change the method but the way you call it

Comment: I understand, but I need to call to this._us.facebookRegisterObs ONLY  if verifyFacebookUser2  gets error on this._us.verifyRegisterFacebookObs(userFacebook ) and this error returns 404 status ...Your way will execute if error appears somewhere flow.